# How to get text from TextView inside a CardView?

Tags: java, android, gettext, android-cardview, cardview

Inside a `CardView` I have a `LinearLayout` with three `TextViews` in it and I want to get the text from these TextViews. My XML-file looks like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/defense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardCB"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:cardElevation="0dp">

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/innerLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:text="Rannochia"
                  android:textAlignment="center"
                  android:textStyle="bold"/>
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:text="78"
                  android:textAlignment="center"
                  android:textStyle="bold"/>
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:text="CB"
                  android:textAlignment="center"
                  android:textStyle="bold"/>

          </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
       </LinearLayout>
```

Then I want to **iterate** through all CardViews in the parent LinearLayout and get the TextViews. Something like this:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < defense.getChildCount(); i++){
        String getName = ((CardView)defense.getChildAt(i)).getText().toString();
        id[i] = getName;
    }
```

But I'm not able to call the methods `getText().toString();` like this. How can I get the text from these TextViews inside the CardView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So many options in here. 

1. Give id for your TextViews

2. Use `for` in LinearLayout with id `innerLayout`

3. When your UI is dynamic and you need to get TextViews from defense

```
for (int i = 0; i < defense.getChildCount(); i++){
        CardView card = defense.getChildAt(i);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = ((ViewGroup)card.getChildAt(0));
        for(int j=0;j<viewGroup.getChildCount();j++){
            String getName = ((TextView)viewGroup.getChildAt(j)).getText().toString();
            id[i] = getName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfect, espacially when I have more than one CardView.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the reference to TextView

```
    for (int i = 0; i < defense.getChildCount(); i++){
        String getName = ((TextView)defense.getChildAt(i)).getText().toString();
        id[i] = getName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It not works because the textview is inside another ViewGroup which is @+id/innerLayout..

i make a simple function for you..

```
private void loopViews(ViewGroup view) {
for (int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = view.getChildAt(i);

    if (v instanceof EditText) {
        // will be executed when its edittext
        Log.d("Check", "This is EditText");

    } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
        // will be executed when its textview,, and get the text..
        TextView x = (TextView) v;
        String aa = x.getText().toString();
        Log.d("Check", "This is TextView with text : " +aa);

    } else if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {

        // will be executed when its viewgroup,, and loop it for get the child view..
        Log.d("Check", "This is ViewGroup");
        this.loopViews((ViewGroup) v);
    }
}
```

and you can use it like this..

```
    LinearLayout def = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.defense);
    loopViews(def);
```

hope it can help you.. :)